# Understanding python slice syntax

Tags: python, numpy, slice

```
N = 100 # number of points per class
D = 2 # dimensionality
K = 3 # number of classes
X = np.zeros((N*K,D))
y = np.zeros(N*K, dtype='uint8')
for j in xrange(K):
  ix = range(N*j,N*(j+1))
  r = np.linspace(0.0,1,N) # radius
  t = np.linspace(j*4,(j+1)*4,N) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # theta
  X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]
  y[ix] = j
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.xlim([-1,1])
plt.ylim([-1,1])
plt.show()
```

This was the code and it's from here: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cs231nfiles/minimal_net.html

The only thing I don't understand here is this line:

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
```

How can we do that (X[:, 0]) with lists and what this operation does?

Comment: `X` is  NumPy array, not a list. `X[:, 0]` simply slices the second axis. Try `X.shape` / `X.ndim` to check the shape of your array.

Comment: Oh,thanks. I'll definitely checkout the numpy documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is not a builtin python list. It's a numpy array. Have a look at the documentation for `zeros`
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

and indexing arrays:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html